# How do I set the text value of a ComboBox to the output of a function in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I cannot seem to get the combobox text value to display the output of a function. Its behaving extremely strangely.

All of these work:

```
item.Text = "test";
```

```
string testStr = "test";
item.Text = testStr;
```

```
string testStr = "test" + function();
item.Text = testStr;
```

```
string testStr = " " + function();
item.Text = testStr;
```

These do not work

```
item.Text = function();
```

```
testStr = "" + function();
item.Text = testStr;
```

I'm about to tear my hair out. Please help me.

I listed above what I tried. Its worth noting that the function is working fine in every other situation, and it outputs a normal string without issue. I just need this to work:

item.Text = function();

The function is:

```
public static string getStringFromDB(string sqlStr)
{
    string result = null;

    SqlConnection conn;
    conn = openCon();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStr, conn);
    try
    {
        result = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result = getIntFromDB(sqlStr).ToString();

    }

    closeConn(conn);
    return result;
}
```

Edit: I have now discovered that the following messagebox displays properly, but the Combobox does not display any data.

```
item.Text = getStringFromDB("SELECT " + dbStrings[2] + " FROM " + dbStrings[0] + " WHERE " + dbStrings[1] + " = " + getIntFromDB("SELECT " + item.Name + " FROM MASTER WHERE MASTER_ID = " + recordID + ";"));
MessageBox.Show(item.Text);
```

Edit: This morning, the code was working fine after no changes were made. I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: Can we see what function() does ?

Comment: I have edited the post to contain the function.

Comment: Check that the result have something before returning it

Comment: hmm, that's strange. What kind of object is `item`? How do you know it doesn't work? Have you debuged the combobox and checked the `items`collection and examine the elements in the list?

Comment: The function is outputting fine to a message box without issue. I can store it in another variable, but that still doesnt help.

Comment: item is a reference to the ComboBox. The items in the combo box are being pulled from an sql server. The text I am trying to assign to the combobox is also being pulled directly from the same table on the server

Comment: I dont know what kind of object you use as the combo list item, remember that the display value will be the ToString() unless you specify otherwise in the ComboBox.DisplayMember. So that makes sense it works for the msgbox but not in the combo. I agree ut looks strange that is doesnot work. But Inthink we need to know that object type you use as the Item

Comment: @steb are you suggesting that I put .ToString() at the end of my function/variable with function output? Because that is also not working for me...

Comment: Ah I see, so the `item` is of type ComboBox? And when you set the item.Text you are trying to set the text property of the combo box. I thought the item was an object you added to the combo box's items collection. And that child item needs to have an overridden ToString() to give the right text to the combobox (if you dont use the DisplayMember of the combobox). Could it be that you have the combo's DropDownStyle set to "DropDownList" and that you dont have a matching child item in the list? But that wont explain your working-thing by going through a variable.

Comment: You are correct. I am able to set that property to anything, regardless of list contents, just not using that function. It makes no sense to me. Even more confusing, I am not seeing this issue this morning. I made no changes to that part of the code. Weird. Thanks for the help!

Comment: :-) super strange

Answer (score 0):

I am closing this, as the code is working this morning. I did not make any changes to the code since posting this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

It seems like the issue is with the function getStringFromDB(string sqlStr).
It appears that the function is working fine in all other situations, but it's not working when you assign its return value to the Text property of the combobox item.

Here are a few things you can try:

Verify the return value of the function: Make sure that the function is returning a string value as expected. You can check this by adding a temporary line of code to print the return value of the function to the console before assigning it to the combobox item's Text property.

Check for null values: Make sure that the function is not returning a null value. If it is, you'll need to handle that case in your code.

Check the combobox item's Text property: Make sure that the combobox item's Text property is accessible and can be set.

Check for any exceptions: Make sure that there are no exceptions being thrown when you assign the return value of the function to the combobox item's Text property. If there are, make sure to handle them appropriately.

If the function is working fine in other situations but not working here, you may try calling the function and storing the result in a variable, and then assign the variable to the combobox's Text property.

Comment: I appreciate the help! Unfortunately, I have tried all of these prior to writing this post...

Comment: Although it is feedback on how someone can find an issue, it isn't sufficient to be an answer on the question. since you only give tips and no conclusive answer. Therefore I advice you next time to write such suggestions in comments.